# Method for adding sub-section to an inline admin in Django?

Tags: python, django

So like the title says. I am building a book structure and I am looking to make it so when in the admin panel and editing a book object, one can view and add related pages to the book. The page itself also has related objects called sections that are essentially paragraph objects within the page object.

My model is below:

```
class Textbook(models.Model):
    founder = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Page(models.Model):
    textbook = models.ForeignKey(Textbook,related_name="pages")
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    page_num = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_title

class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page,related_name="sections")
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 1024)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_title
```

Ideally there would be an add new page button within the textbook add/edit panel where I could then add section to that previously mentioned page.

Current admin.py:

```
class PageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page

class TextbookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PageInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Textbook,TextbookAdmin)
admin.site.register(Section)
```

Is there a currently built in method like a nest inline that could be used or I am just not thinking in the right mindset for Django? If this is not the proper or ideal way to structure this, what is the proper method?

Comment: __This is off topic__: You should consider not to model a page. Content is a stream - you only need pages, when it comes to printing. Have a look at [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/).

Comment: What do you mean content is a stream? I am not following. I am organizing my data this way for specific reasons. Would it be possible for you to help while operating within these parameters.

Comment: As I told you, the comment was quite off topic - I just wanted to point out, that the model structure might lead to several problems. If you have good reasons to stick with it - just stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the structure perhaps the easiest solution is to use [Django Nested Inline package](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) and thus keeping everything in one view.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin

from .models import Textbook, Page, Section


class SectionInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Section
    extra = 1


class PageInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Page
    extra = 1
    inlines = [SectionInline]


@admin.register(Textbook)
class TextbookAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PageInline]
```

Comment: Great thanks! Would you suggest a better method. I am open to advice. I am just looking to make it so books and pages can be very modular.

Comment: Honestly, google around for some alternative way to save you book structure. This structure isn't very modular :D my answer is specific to your models and it works, but in the end it's on you how you will structure your data.